# Parse push notification opens app automatically without tapping on the notification

Tags: android, parse-platform

The problem is that when my app is in the Background and I get a notification it directly opens the app without me tapping on the Notification, can't figure out why!

Here's my Parse Package:

```
  @Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent == null)
        return;

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

        parseIntent = intent;

        parsePushJson(context, json);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("PushJsonException", ""+e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void parsePushJson(Context context, JSONObject getJson) {
    Log.d("ParsePushJson", getJson.toString());
   // AppController.getInstance().addDeletedItem(getJson.toString());


    String title = "Twine";
    String message = getJson.toString();
    String fromNotification = getJson.toString();


            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Dashboard.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("fromNotification",message);
            showNotificationMessage(context, title, message, resultIntent);

        }




private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message,
                                     Intent resultIntent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);

    resultIntent.putExtras(parseIntent.getExtras());

    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, resultIntent);

}

@Override
protected void onPushDismiss(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushDismiss(context, intent);
}

@Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
}
```

Here's my Notification Utils:

```
class ForegroundCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
        final Context context = params[0].getApplicationContext();
        return isAppOnForeground(context);
    }

    private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (appProcesses == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
            if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message,
                                    Intent intent) {

    boolean foreground = false;

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;

    try {
        foreground = new ForegroundCheckTask().execute(AppController.getInstance()).get();
        Log.d("fromForeground", Boolean.toString(foreground));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (foreground)
    {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        int smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        int mNotificationId = AppConfig.NOTIFICATION_ID;

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);
        Notification notification = mBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(
                        RingtoneManager
                                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setLargeIcon(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, notification);

        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);


    } else
    {
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
         mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put all these lines

```
intent.putExtra("title", title);
intent.putExtra("message", message);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

after

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Dashboard.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("fromNotification",message);
```

and remove

```
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

If you are using `notification` there is no need of `startActivity()`, pending intent will handle it

Answer (score 0):

You can modify you class like Below.

```
 public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onReceive(context, intent);

          Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            String message = extras != null ? extras.getString("com.parse.Data") : "";
            JSONObject jObject;
            try {
                    jObject = new JSONObject(message);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
       @Override
       public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {

          Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
          String jsonData = extras.getString( "com.parse.Data" );

          String uriString = null;
          try
          {
             JSONObject pushData = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("com.parse.Data"));
              Intent iv = new Intent(context,PlaceDetailsUserKeep.class);
              context.startActivity(iv);

          }
          catch (JSONException e)
          {
             //Parse.logE("com.parse.ParsePushReceiver", "Unexpected JSONException when receiving push data: ", e);
          }

       }
    }
```